# Creating Credential to run SQL Server Agent Job on Server NOT on a domain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-server-identity

I have set up a SQL Server on an EC2 instance that is NOT on a domain.

I need the SQL Server Agent to run SSIS scripts, do back ups, send DB Mail, . I have set up a sql server user with read / write db permissions, and tried to follow the instructions here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-a-user-to-create-and-manage-sql-server-agent-jobs

After doing some research the Job needs to run on a Proxy, which requires a Credential. When I try to create a new credential I click on the elipsis next to Identity and I get the error

"The program cannot open the required dialog box because it cannot determine whether the computer named 'BLAHBLAHBLAH' is joined to a domain. Close this message and try again."

To be clear I only need the account to run SSIS jobs, back ups and send the occasional mail.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: So I figured out that I needed to set the log on property in the SQL Server Agent in Sql Server Configuration Manager. Is this secure?